# how to update an attribute of an object (which is fetched based on a condition) in a list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any way to update an object in the list for which we pose an codition.

`offer = offers.FirstOrDefault(o => o.attribute.Equals("Match"));
offer.property ="updatedvalue";`

I would like to use the offers in my code which should have the updated property of offer object.

Comment: I don't know what `offer` is, but if it is mutable there's no reason you can't use whatever fields/settable properties/methods it exposes.

Comment: Theres no way you are actually asking how to mutate `offer`. Is there some context we are missing here? Do you not understand how references work? Is `offer` a value type?

Comment: offer is a object of some type A and offers is the list of object of type A. I would like to update a property on offer which should reflect in offers and I should be able to use it. Do you need more clarity on what I am looking for let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Then just mutate it, as in the answer. You have a simple reference, mutating what it points to will be reflected in all other references. Note that if it is `int` or another value type, this will *not* work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just update the attributes after you filter and then use it,

```
offer = offers.FirstOrDefault(o => o.attribute.Equals("Match"));
offer.Property1 = "NewValue";
............................;
```

then use the offer object again.

Comment: I would like to use the offers object again not just the updated offer object and the offers should contain the newly set property value.

Comment: @reddy_rocks So you want to save a copy off?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET if i update offer will that be reflected in offers list?

Comment: Yes, obviously. *Its just a reference*. The reference in the list is the *same one* that is stored in `offer`. They point at the *same object*. If this is confusing, you *really* need to go back and learn about references (perhaps look at pointers, as they are *roughly* what references are based on).

Comment: @reddy_rocks LINQ is just querying; its a way to get objects (references) out of a collection. It *doesn't* change the underlying type structure.